# Mockito static method verification InOrder

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to verify the static methods present in a class InOrder.
Below is the sample class that is having a few static methods

```
public class SampleClass {
  public static void staticMethod1(Param1 param)
  {
     //doSomething
  }
  public static void staticMethod2(Param2 param)
  {
     //doSomething
  }
  public static void staticMethod2(Param3 param)
  {
     //doSomething
  }
}

public class parent{
  public void method() {
    SampleClass.staticMethod1(...);
    SampleClass.staticMethod2(...);
    SampleClass.staticMethod3(...);
  }
}
```

And my test looks like this

```
@Test
public void test(){
  try (MockedStatic<SamplClass > mockSamplClass = mockStatic(SamplClass .class, Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS))
  {
    //doStuff
    mockSampleClass.verify(()->SampleClass.staticMethod1(...));
    mockSampleClass.verify(()->SampleClass.staticMethod2(...));
    mockSampleClass.verify(()->SampleClass.staticMethod3(...));
  }
}
```

Is there any way to perform InOrder verification for the three static methods?
As Mockito.inOrder takes in only mock types and not MockedStatic types.

Right now I am kind of looking for answers in Mockito not involving PowerMockito.

Comment: You need to fix your design. What do these "static methods" do that is void? That smells like side effects, so test those side effects directly. If you can't, that's a sign that the side effects shouldn't be buried in static methods.

Comment: This doesn't look to be a good test case either.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, these are legacy code and won't be able to update the code/design. These methods deal with closing the sql related objects.
Currently am trying migrate from jmockit to mockito. Under jmockit these were declared under VerificationInOrder block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those that found this question as the 1st result on Google like me, now Mockito supports this. Using your example:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  try (MockedStatic<SamplClass > mockSamplClass = mockStatic(SamplClass.class, Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
    //doStuff
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(SamplClass.class);
    inOrder.verify(mockSampleClass, ()-> SampleClass.staticMethod1(...));
    inOrder.verify(mockSampleClass, ()-> SampleClass.staticMethod2(...));
    inOrder.verify(mockSampleClass, ()-> SampleClass.staticMethod3(...));
  }
}
```

For more info see the [Mockito github issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2548)